# WooCommerce - Create Customer using API

Tags: wordpress, api, ionic-framework, woocommerce

I want to create a signup page for my WooCommerce Store (in my external app) . Unfortunately, whenever I call the API to create a customer, it says it is missing the password parameter.

Makes totally sense, but the WooCommerce API docs dont tell me anything how to pass the password that the user selects on the signup page: http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-customer

How would I change my code to make it work?

```
this.WooCommerce = WC({


        url: "https://.......mystagingwebsite.com/",
        consumerKey: 'ck_....', // Production
        consumerSecret: 'cs_....', // Production
        wpAPI: true,
        version: 'wc/v2'

    });

    var data = {
      email: 'john.doe@example.com',
      first_name: 'John',
      last_name: 'Doe',
      username: 'john.doe',
      billing: {
        first_name: 'John',
        last_name: 'Doe',
        company: '',
        address_1: '969 Market',
        address_2: '',
        city: 'San Francisco',
        state: 'CA',
        postcode: '94103',
        country: 'US',
        email: 'john.doe@example.com',
        phone: '(555) 555-5555'
      },
      shipping: {
        first_name: 'John',
        last_name: 'Doe',
        company: '',
        address_1: '969 Market',
        address_2: '',
        city: 'San Francisco',
        state: 'CA',
        postcode: '94103',
        country: 'US'
      }
    };


    this.WooCommerce.post('customers', data, function(err, data, res) {

          console.log(res);

    });
```

Comment: I had a look at the source code - ...\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\api\class-wc-rest-customers-controller.php. It shows a parameter 'password'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the REST schema by executing the curl command:

```
curl -X OPTIONS http://me.local.com/wp-json/wc/v2/customers
```

Unfortunately, this gives raw JSON so it is better to put it in a file first.

```
curl -X OPTIONS http://me.local.com/wp-json/wc/v2/customers > curl.out
```

This can be decode with the PHP command:

```
php -r "print_r( json_decode( file_get_contents( 'curl.out' ) ) );" > php.out
```

You want to look for the endpoint with method 'POST' for create REST request.

Alternatively, you can just read the REST controller source code at:

```
...\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\api
```

In either case this will be more accurate then any documentation as it reflects the current implementation.

If you do this you will find a parameter 'password' which has the property 'required' => 1 which is why your request is failing. So, I would insert a 'password' parameter between 'username' and 'billing'.

Comment: Hey Magenta Cuda, thanks for the feedback. The thing is I am writing a native app using ionic framework (Angular, Javascript/Typescript, html. So curl does not seem to be applicable in my case?!

Comment: curl is an extremely useful command line tool for sending HTTP requests. It can be used to download files, e.g. I use it to download YouTube movies. Here I am using it to download the schema for the REST customer endpoint  as it is currently implemented. As you can see the WooCommerce documentation is not always accurate but the schema will be as the schema is what drives the REST server - similar to the schema in an SQL database. curl can also be used to test REST requests before you write any code. See https://curl.haxx.se/ and http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/